# Deploy Web App Azure issues

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm new to deploying a web app to Azure (using Azure App Service).  My app has about 6 web projects and we also use Umbraco CMS.  When I build the web app in Visual Studio and point to any of our databases (dev, stage, etc.), the web site works locally (localhost)

When I try to publish the app to Azure or even test it locally (after "convert"), content is missing and all the links have the incorrect domain.  I'm following MS docs to "Migrate and Publish a web app  to Azure Cloud".

The first step in the MS docs is to right-click on the web app and select "Convert > Convert to Microsoft Azure".  After this step I try to test the Web App created by this step.  I point to the same databases as if i build locally (not using "convert"), content is missing and links have a different domain.

Is there a settings in the web.config or other file I need to do when building/deploying to Azure cloud service?

Comment: WebApp and Cloud services are two different services from Azure so the document you were following might be of Cloud services suggestion you to check this link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/migration-checklist-when-moving-to-azure-app-service/

Comment: I am going to assume that you are using azure website as you have tagged Azure Website in the question. You can always override the application settings and connection string settings thru azure portal.See here:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/blog/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/ . Try updating your settings accordingly & see you get positive outcome. Also on azure website, have you configured custom domains by any chance?

Comment: One of the issues was definitely what Faroq alluded to...this is a Web App and I deployed incorrectly.  Other issue is me being unfamiliar with Umbraco.  Turns out needed to set the domain for the site in Umbraco settings

Answer (score 0):

If you have knowledges in Docker, I recommend to use it. In Azure, you have the possibility to create a "web app for container".

After you create your docker-compose.yml, you go to azure and create a resource, and now you create an "azure container registry".

After that, you create a "Web app for containers" and choose your registry.
In Docker Tab, you can choose docker-compose and select your docker-compose.yml file locally.

Azure will deploy automatically your web app!